# How to get property of class handle after override in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand UVM Override.
I was made a simple Override example as the below

```
    module test_module ();
`include "uvm_macros.svh"
  import uvm_pkg::*;
 
  class agent_a extends uvm_agent;
    `uvm_component_utils(agent_a)
 
    function new(string name = "agent_a", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
  endclass : agent_a
 
  class agent_b extends agent_a;
    `uvm_component_utils(agent_b)
 
    string field = "agent_b.field";
 
    function new(string name = "agent_b", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
  endclass : agent_b
  
    class agent_c extends uvm_env;
      `uvm_component_utils(agent_c)
 
    string field = "agent_c.field";
 
      function new(string name = "agent_c", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
  endclass : agent_c
  
 
  agent_a agent_a_h;
 
  initial begin
    
    agent_a::type_id::set_type_override(agent_c::get_type());
    factory.print();

    agent_a_h = agent_a::type_id::create("agent_a_h", null);

    $display("field = ", agent_a_h.field);
    
  end
endmodule : test_module
```

When I ran the above simulation. I encounter below Error message.

```
    $display("field = ", agent_a_h.field);
                                       |
xmvlog: *E,NOTCLM (testbench.sv,46|39): field is not a class item.
```

If I understand as well about override, I can use **agent_c** class instead **agent_a** after override.

then agent_a agent_a_h; becomes agent_c agent_a_h;

then it could be displayed agent_a_h.field without error .

but why does it say as "field" is not a class item?

#update question for override from derived class

```
module test_module ();
`include "uvm_macros.svh"
  import uvm_pkg::*;
 
  class agent_a extends uvm_agent;
    `uvm_component_utils(agent_a)
 
    function new(string name = "agent_a", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
    
    virtual function display();
      $display("agent_a.display1");
    endfunction
    
  endclass : agent_a
 
  class agent_b extends agent_a;
    `uvm_component_utils(agent_b)
 
    string field = "agent_b.field";
 
    function new(string name = "agent_b", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
    
        
    virtual function display();
      $display("agent_b.display2");
    endfunction
    
    
  endclass : agent_b
  
    class agent_c extends uvm_agent;
      `uvm_component_utils(agent_c)
 
    string field = "agent_c.field";
 
      function new(string name = "agent_c", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction : new
      
              
    virtual function display();
      $display("agent_c.display3");
    endfunction
    
  endclass : agent_c
  
 
  agent_a agent_a_h;


 
  initial begin

    agent_a::type_id::set_type_override(agent_c::get_type());
    factory.print();

    agent_a_h = agent_a::type_id::create("agent_a_h", null);

   // $display("field = ", agent_a_h.field);
    
    agent_a_h.display();
    
  end
endmodule : test_module
```

I update code as the above, for figure out What if there are 2 class extended uvm_agent,
##################################################################

What If I want drv2 class to add into old testbench( drv class),
Does it impossible to override between drv2 class and drv?
Should I have to add drv2 class below to C orc D in drv class hierachy?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`agent_a_h` is of type `agent_a`, and as a result, it contains no such field.

First of all, you cannot override `agetn_a` with `agent_c`. Those classes are unrelated and there is no way to use factory override to do so. You will get run-time errors here.

In object-oriented programming in order to do something with a derived class objects through a base class pointer, you should use a virtual function.

I demonstrated these 2 points in modified code below.

1. created a virtual function *getField()*
2. used agent_b to override

```
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

module test_module ();
   import uvm_pkg::*;
   
class agent_a extends uvm_agent;
   `uvm_component_utils(agent_a)
   
   function new(string name = "agent_a", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
   endfunction : new
   
   virtual function string getField(); //<<<<<<
      return "";
   endfunction
   
endclass : agent_a
   
class agent_b extends agent_a;
   `uvm_component_utils(agent_b)
   
   string  field = "agent_b.field";
   
   function new(string name = "agent_b", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
   endfunction : new
   
   virtual function string getField(); // <<<<<<<
      return field;
   endfunction
endclass : agent_b
      
   agent_a agent_a_h;
   
   initial begin
      agent_a::type_id::set_type_override(agent_b::get_type()); // <<<<<<
      agent_a_h = agent_a::type_id::create("agent_a_h", null);

      $display("field = ", agent_a_h.getField());
   end
endmodule : test_module
```

Answering your *update*: there is no way to override **base class** drv with an non-related class *drv2*. The classes for override must have parent/child type relation ship in order for that.

But in your case, they have a common **uvm_agent** class parent. If you use **it** as a base class, than you can override it either with *drv* or *drv2*.

That means that you have to plan accordingly.

=======================
Here is some extra explanation for your comment question. Currently you have the following type inheritance:

```
uvm_agent --> agent_a
          |   |--> agent_b
          |--> agent_c
```

You use `agent_a` as a base pointer: `agent_a agent_a_h;`
This allows you to override *agent_a* with *agent_b* *when* you create *agent_a_h*. Basically the factory create an object of type *agent_b* and assigns it to the handle of its super class type (agent_a).

This cannot be done with *agent_c* because *agent_a* is not its base class.

To fix this problem you should notice that `uvm_agent` is eventually a base class for all of those classes. Therefore, it could be used as such in overrides:

```
   uvm_agent handle;
   ...
   uvm_agent::type_id::set_type_override(agent_X::get_type());
   handle = uvm_env::type_id::create("agent_X_handle", null);
```

without uvm it could be expressed as the following.

```
   uvm_agent handle;
   agent_X agent_X_h = new;
   handle = agent_X_H;
```

Now, the problem is that the *uvm_agent* class is a third-party library class and does not have any of the members which you care about, e.g. 'display'

The solution I suggested is following this scheme:

```
uvm_agent --> my_agent  --> agent_a
                        |   |--> agent_b
                        |--> agent_c
```

where my_agent is a virtual class containing the functions you need:

```
class my_agent extends uvm_agent;
     virtual function void display();
     endfunction
     ...
endclass
class agent_a extends my_agent; ...
class agent_b extends agent_a; ...
class agent_c extends my_agent; ...
```

In this case you can have *my_agent* as a base handle and do your overrides to any of the class types in the tree:

overrides:

```
   my_agent handle;
   ...
   my_agent::type_id::set_type_override(agent_X::get_type());
   handle = my_agent::type_id::create("agent_X_handle", null);
```

Comment: I figure out that 1. Must use Virtual, 2. Must be derived relationship between them for override.

Comment: I have a simple question relative reply about 2. I've update the question.

Comment: I made https://www.edaplayground.com/x/AztA example . but still error. Did I someting miss from(But in your case, they have a common uvm_agent class parent. If you use it as a base class, than you can ovveride it either with drv or drv2.)?

Comment: yes, base class must be uvm_agent, not agent_a. But uvm_agent has no *display* function. So, it will not work.  You either need to create your own base class derived from uvm_agent, e.g. 'my_uvm_agent' and define all your virtual functions in it. Then you have to design your agent classes as derived from my_uvm_agent. You use it as a base class reference for overrides. These all are techniques used in generic object oriented programming.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask you reference code(elaborate) your last answer for clear understanding? I think I pretty much understand but I need to clear idea from your last answer by some code.. Could you please help me ?

Comment: i added more explanation to my answer.